# Solar car ventilation system

Tags: power, solar-cell, panel

I am a mechanical engineering student and for my final project I am designing a solar car ventilation system so I need to know how much power the air conditioner of a car (Mazda Lantis 323 2001) fan needs to get from solar panel(12V) in order to operate properly?

Comment: Use a clamp-on DC meter to measure the fan current. Then calculate power from P = VI. Most air-conditioning heat pumps are driven by a belt from the engine. No engine rotation? No air-con!

Comment: Most ac pumps need 6 or 8 horsepower...

Answer (score 0):

The compressor won't work, but you can circulate some air perhaps.

According to [this blog](https://macsworldwide.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/blower-motor-draw/) the interior fan takes anywhere from 5 to 20 Amps depending of speed switch.
It's a simple 12V radial fan.

I estimate this being similar in all ICE cars. This part isn't reinvented a lot.